# Ubuntu 18.04 installed RTX 2080 and recently compiled and running program will no longer run, are there conflicting drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have been trying to get a wxWidgets program to compile on Ubuntu 18.04. At the time, my RTX 2080 had not come in yet and I was using a coworkers 1060 in the mean time. Last Friday, I finally was able to compile the program I was working on and I got it to run, which required the OpenCL and OpenGL Libraries. I installed these libraries which I believe are required for the program to run:

```
mesa-utils libeglw1-mesa libglw1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev freeglut3 ocl-icd-opencl-dev
```

I also installed the Cuda 10 Libraries from NVIDIA as well.

My RTX 2080 finally came in, I installed the graphics card and only one monitor worked at a terrible resolution, I realized that I needed to download official NVIDIA drivers. Once I got those installed my monitors returned back to normal. However, now when I try to run the program I get the error:

```
(Program:18499): Gdk-ERROR **: 09:45:23.055: The program 'Program' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)'.
  (Details: serial 228 error_code 2 request_code 151 (GLX) minor_code 3)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

Which this could be a legitimate bug in the program, however, it is a little strange to me on why before the 2080 my program ran just fine. I've tried running GDB like this:

```
GDK_SYNCHRONIZE="1" gdb ./Program
```

However, I don't really know where to break on the program and if I try setting a break point on `gdk_x_error()` GDB cannot find the function to break on. So at this point I am at a loss on where to go from here. I don't really want to reinstall my distro, but if I have to I will. When I searched for an error, I was directed to this site: https://github.com/cjcliffe/CubicSDR/issues/569, and someone in that thread said:

"A quick search on the Internet suggests a problem related to GLX libraries vs. drivers (Intel, Nvidia) and re-installing them. Please also note that wxWidgets 3.11 must be compiled with OpenGL support for CubicSDR to work."

However I wasn't sure if that error was specific to CubicSDR or if this is the same issue. Does anyone have any ideas on what I can try?

Comment: IMO, it’s borderline.   Some people will believe that this question belongs on [SO]; some will vehemently insist that it does.   I suggest that you wait a couple of days.   If you don’t get a satisfactory response here, then flag your message for a moderator to migrate it.   Please do not repost this question on [SO] unless this copy gets deleted, or a moderator refuses to move it.

Comment: @G-Man thank you. I will continue my search and see if I can solve it. If I don't get an answer by Monday, then I will flag for it to be Migrated. Rui made an edit removing the "I am not sure if this belongs here or on Stackoverflow." But I will wait patiently.

Comment: @G-Man would this be on topic on [so]? There's no code here. The OP is trying to install a program, not writing it, why would that be on topic on SO?

Comment: @Sailanarmo you don't need to ask a mod to migrate. If you want to move your question elsewhere, you can simply delete this and post it on the other site. G-man meant that you shouldn't have the same question on both sites, but deleting here and then reposting is fine. Flagging is also fine, I just wanted to let you know you could do it yourself too. All that said, I don't really know if this would be on topic on SO.

Comment: I just asked an [so] moderator and he confirmed that this wouldn't really be on topic on SO. Sorry :/

Comment: @terdon thank you. And to defend G-Man, this is a program I am trying to install that I previously had working from code that I modified within the program. The program ran fine with the 1060. But as soon as I installed the RTX 2080 and tried to run the code again, the program stopped launching and gave me that error. So maybe it could be code related. However I am not sure, I posted here in since it seems more hardware and unix related. Thank you for checking with a SO moderator for me!

Comment: Ah, that makes things significantly different. In that case, I would leave this question here and post a new one on [so], showing the code you modified. Of course, first make sure the program runs as expected without your modifications. But if it does and your modifications broke it, then fixing that would indeed be on topic for SO. And there's no reason to defend G-man, he did nothing wrong!

Comment: I suspect you ended up with a combination nvidia drivers, runtime- and development libraries for OpenGL and CUDA from the repositories and the installer. There are many ways for these to create version mismatches (as outlined [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472982/nvdia-drivers-on-linux-mint-19-tara/473056#473056)). As you claim to need bleeding edge technology, I recommend you purge all distribution supplied nvidia-related software and then install the nvidia-suppled variants only.

Comment: @Hermann, is this as simple as following the instructions on that link you provided? If not, what order should I begin purging drivers? Should I start with CUDA, the NVIDIA drivers I installed Post Cuda, or OpenCL/GL stuff?

Comment: @Sailanarmo Unfortunately, no. You say, you rely on CUDA 10 and a card requiring driver version [410](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html) or newer. Ubuntu 18.04 comes with [CUDA 9.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/nvidia-cuda-toolkit) only. You can try to uninstall the nvidia provided driver first. Then run `apt purge nvidia-driver-.* nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-.* nvidia-cuda-toolkit`. Reboot just to make sure. Re-install the drivers, then the CUDA toolkit both as provided by nvidia. From afar, I cannot say much more without personally sitting at your system.

Comment: @Hermann well, I guess if that doesn't work I can always nuke and reload the OS.